# FillColor on Highcharts working differently

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What I'm trying to do is to fill individual symbols with a certain color based on how it's performing against it's goal. It used to work, but for some reason no longer is. I've tried to  figure out where the issue is, but couldn't figure it out:

```
    var seriesColor = "#000";
    preprocessData = function (divId, data, last, goal) {
        var nData = []; var symbol = "diamond"; var radius = 5;
        var colorGood = '#348017'; var colorBad = '#E42217'; var colorUse;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] <= goal[i]) { colorUse = colorGood; }
            else if (data[i] > goal[1] * 1.17) { colorUse = colorBad; }
            else { colorUse = '#FFE303'; }
            if((divId == "WebServItRun" || divId == "ISOServicesRun") && i == 9 ){
                symbol = "circle";
                radius = 10;
            }
            else if((divId == "WebServItRun" || divId == "ISOServicesRun") && i != 7){
                symbol = "diamond";
                radius = 5;
            }
            nData.push({
                y: data[i],
                x: i,
                color: colorUse,
                fillColor: colorUse,
                marker: {
                    symbol: symbol,
                    radius: radius
                }
            });
        }
        seriesColor = colorUse;
        return nData;
    };
```

Then in the series calls:

```
    {
            type: 'spline',
            name: series2,
            data: preprocessData(divId, current, last, goal),
            color: seriesColor,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'diamond'
            }
        }
```

Any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set the fill color of the marker, then the fillColor declaration needs to be inside the marker object.

so, this:

```
        fillColor: colorUse,
        marker: {
            symbol: symbol,
            radius: radius
        }
```

should be this:

```
    marker: {
        fillColor: colorUse,
        symbol: symbol,
        radius: radius
    }
```